# D3 line chart doesn't do transition while appending data to chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am working on adding transition to the line chart, copied a example from  [here`http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8`](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8), i want the line chart to do transition when the interval happens, like in the example when you click the button the chart will move to left but in my [plunker`https://plnkr.co/edit/sCJYfXDSjXN1IiFokK1V?p=preview`](https://plnkr.co/edit/sCJYfXDSjXN1IiFokK1V?p=preview) doesn't work, I put the d3 code in angular's custom directive because i have a requirement where graph will be repeated more than 5 times any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update data function, selection of the chart was var `svg = d3.select("lineChart").transition();`. It should be `var svg = d3.select(".lineChart").transition();`

Comment: thank you for pointing it out, i've one more question here, as i said in the question i want to repeat custom directive more than once,  when i put the directive in ng-repeat, the graph displays for all the object but doesn't update on interval for some reason.

Comment: All the charts are getting rendered under the div with class .lineChart. So to select all the charts under that, you need to use selectAll instead of select. `var svg = d3.selectAll(".lineChart svg").transition();`

Comment: Thank you for your time @Gunner